# whirlpool front load washer won't fill with water

Tags: washing-machine, washer

I have a Whirlpool front-load washer. It worked normally. Yesterday, when I try to use it after just finishing a road trip, I found it just did not fill with water. I checked the hot and cold water faucet, and also ensured the hose is not kinked.
Are there any suggestions for the possible failure cause? Thanks.

Comment: There are usually screens on the hoses to prevent rust and scale from clogging the valves. Usually you will notice the washer taking a long time to fill before they totally plug up. They are an easy fix if this is the problem. Turn the water off remove the hose and screen and flush them out in a sink. Installing a new seal is a good idea so it doesn't leak after reassembled. I also get a bucket and flow water from each hose to flush out any loose stuff in the lines.

Comment: The mesh on these screens is extremely fine.  I'm finding that I have to pull them out, and soak them in CLR for half an hour.  Mostly it's just a few thousandths of an inch of iron oxide plated out.  The washing machine doesn't seem to fill more slowly, but it stops with an error code.